# PHP - Equivalent for Python PDB(Debugger) in PHP?

Tags: php, python, debugging

I'm essentially a PHP coder that started to code some things in Python. I'm amazed with [Python PDB](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html), there is something equivalent to PHP?

I'm working with a PHP Web Framework and I'd like specially of the `pdb.set_trace()` that is very useful when we are working with a web framework in Python.

My question is, there is something equivalent for PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Free PHP debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494288/good-free-php-debugger)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing a PHP Debugger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645081/choosing-a-php-debugger)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug PHP code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243572/how-to-debug-php-code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using an IDE, then it should have built in debugging functions for stepping into, over code and the usual suite of functions. I use [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/) myself.

Having said that, I have used the following:

- [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to dump variables and objects
- [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to generate a backtrace of code execution

If you can install extensions on your server, [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) is very very nice. It also allows you to profile your code to identify any bottle necks. You can also connect it to a remote debugger to do your debugging using a separate application.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely try [psysh](http://psysh.org/).

It's a better shell for php like ipython and supports also interactive debugging as pdb.

Comment: great suggestion - this should be the accepted answer because this is something that really brings some familiarity to Python developers. which is what I expected to see based on the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a package developing yet called dephpugger.

A video tutorial here: https://youtu.be/__dTd3QFu1k
The lib: https://github.com/tacnoman/dephpugger